# Bold fonts looks weird on mobile device if not zooming

Tags: html, css, mobile, google-fonts

All bold versions of fonts appear strange on mobile device, I made the font enormous for testing purpose and from that it seems the font kind of "doubles" over itself, with a minor offset between them. If and when I zoom to look closer at the text it "becomes" normal - and shows just as it should show (and does show, on desktop browser).

[Non-zoomed printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPPo5.png)

[Zoomed printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOHdL.png)

There's not really any "voodoo" code to show, it's all very basic. All bold fonts just look strange at their shown state unless you pinch-zoom them on mobile. But for the sake of it:

```
.title {
font-size: 30px;
font-family: "Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
font-weight: 500; /* same problem with 900 */
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
color: #000;
text-align: center;
}

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div class="title">
World wide shipping for flat rates!
</div>
```

I tried different browsers on mobile, and all show the same issue. This happens to ALL fonts when bold, not just the one I use in this example.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    <style type="text/css">
        .title {
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 900;
            font-style: normal;
            font-variant: normal;
            color: #000;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<div class="title">World wide shipping for flat rates!</div>
```